# Postgres: empty table though permissions granted to the role

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

I have a problem with SELECT when granting permission for the role.

I need to create a Customer role with the privilege to SELECT from 2 tables.
And then I need to create a personalized role for one client, and GRANT customer to this role.

I did it this way:

```
CREATE ROLE customer;

GRANT SELECT ON public.payment TO customer;
GRANT SELECT ON public.customer TO customer;

ALTER TABLE public.payment ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

CREATE POLICY policy_payments
ON public.payment TO customer
USING (customer_id = (
            SELECT customer_id
            FROM public.customer c
            WHERE 'client_' || lower(c.first_name || '_' || c.last_name) = current_role));
    
CREATE role client_julie_sanchez;

GRANT customer TO client_julie_sanchez;
  
SET ROLE client_julie_sanchez;
SELECT * FROM public.payment p
```

I see an empty table for both roles - Customer and client_julie_sanchez.
What's wrong with the code?

Comment: The granted permissions are irrelevant - that part works, since you are actually allowed to execute the select statement; you don't get an error. The empty result set is caused by the RLS policy rather.

Comment: Which rows do `customer` and  `payment` actually contain?

Comment: @Bergi yes, it seems that the problem is in RLS policy, but I don't know why.

Customer and payment tables contain customer_id and some other columns

Comment: No, I mean which rows, not which columns? Though it would be great if you could add the table definitions to your question as well so that we have a [mre]